# Analysing number of errors with ANOVA in R

Tags: r, dplyr, anova

I have the following dataset

```
library(car)
library(ez)

dat <- structure(list(numbers = c(4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 
8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9), condition = c("controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue"), key = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g"), accuracy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RTs = c(0.433440075489, 
0.584262928925, 0.900921091321, 0.650958113838, 0.384471354773, 
0.484353395877, 0.367676318623, 0.80092431698, 0.600955694448, 
0.417601027526, 0.416974943597, 0.334586234763, 0.351031572558, 
0.450530192116, 0.916829419206, 0.333611185662, 0.517596335616, 
0.384416737361, 0.684295259416, 0.750973949209, 0.767682843842, 
0.450949169695, 0.466901118401, 0.334349070676, 0.450331150103, 
0.650875638006, 0.767181023373, 0.516833524685, 0.317576028174, 
0.434385433211, 1.43416476424, 0.984174514655, 0.684317253064, 
0.484326637001, 0.550981133827, 0.551001294749, 0.500949389767, 
1.33413536614, 0.384293939918, 0.416949284263, 0.384314100724, 
0.484288514825, 0.450997555861, 0.550951809157, 0.617581746541, 
0.650942718377, 0.767599268118, 0.53431109502, 0.451014050981, 
1.11751613207, 1.08416322456, 0.667607259005, 0.567603520118, 
0.567682696972, 0.634281843435, 0.334355668398, 0.334310948383, 
0.417710262351, 0.784255377483, 0.550962439273, 0.750906869303, 
0.434287562035, 0.417775876354, 0.384364685975, 0.434299658053, 
0.484298411757, 0.483843877792, 0.666952216734, 0.417631818564, 
0.434350610012, 0.350977688329, 0.501701937057, 0.434329716023, 
0.401814764133, 0.517609531758, 0.3343586009, 0.500969551038, 
0.46698616026, 0.484318206087, 0.6168882153, 0.416916294023, 
0.401016396936, 0.634216595774, 0.400972409756, 0.81760022114, 
0.417864584015, 0.501075852895, 0.484331035754, 0.467665028758, 
0.867562685395, 0.43438396696, 0.467593549751, 0.517631158698, 
0.367689514998, 0.450537156698, 0.716814610176, 0.467556160642, 
0.400933554512, 0.417823895928, 0.900883702328, 0.834234703798, 
0.36768218386, 0.40100246761, 0.450967864366, 0.550976368599, 
0.45093743992, 0.484216302633, 0.500258058077, 0.61761400383, 
1.11749157286, 0.501043595839, 0.484376122709, 0.500976148527, 
0.351031939033, 0.517575074919, 0.784278837498, 0.867508801108, 
1.01678257284, 0.51763152529, 0.5509294488, 0.617823675973, 0.767636657227, 
0.450994256651, 0.734270920046, 0.734351563035, 0.800978201441, 
0.517633358482, 0.450958700385, 0.400935020763, 0.484300611075, 
0.417713195086, 0.584306549281, 0.367692081258, 0.384340859484, 
0.600864421227, 0.367676685564, 0.351042935858, 0.317690394819, 
0.384351123241, 0.450992057449, 0.484310508356, 0.816703982418, 
0.916879637865, 0.516891807551, 0.417754616123, 0.501040663105, 
0.451032012235, 0.384372383589, 0.550228953362, 0.567485487787, 
0.484277151525, 0.500982380006), participant = c(5, 6, 10, 17, 
21, 22, 27, 29, 29, 30, 32, 35, 38, 5, 10, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 
22, 35, 37, 38, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 
14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 23, 
23, 24, 25, 25, 27, 28, 31, 31, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 1, 1, 11, 
15, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 37, 37, 1, 9, 11, 
11, 19, 19, 22, 24, 26, 27, 34, 37, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 10, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 19, 19, 20, 22, 23, 31, 37, 38, 38, 2, 5, 
7, 12, 17, 20, 22, 26, 26, 29, 29, 35, 35, 35, 36, 37, 37, 38, 
4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 12, 12, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 24, 24, 
29), hand = c("left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right"), parity = c("even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd"
), magnitude = c("small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large"
)), row.names = c(NA, 152L), class = "data.frame")
```

My aim is to perform a 2x2 factorial ANOVA. My two factors will be **hand** and **parity** and my dependent variable is **accuracy** where 1 = correct and 0 = error. I am focusing on errors for my ANOVA so I have filtered so only errors (0's) remain.

Does anybody know how to perform an ANOVA on differences in the number of errors for my factors? My first attempt produced an error:

```
ezANOVA(dat, dv = accuracy, wid = participant, within = .(parity, hand), type = 3, detailed = TRUE, return_aov = TRUE)

Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

I think this is because all of the accuracy values are 0 whereas I want analyse the *number* of 0's (number of errors) for my factorial ANOVA. Hence I then tried to average across each condition and re-ran the ANOVA however I run into more problems.

I'm averaging across subjects so I lose my within subjects variable (thus I cannot use the ezANOVA function). I then try and use the aov() and Anova() functions but generate a new error:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(parity, hand) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(acc_num = n())

result <- aov(acc_num ~ parity * hand, data = dat)
Anova(result, type = 3)

Error in Anova.lm(mod, ...) : residual df = 0
```

Does anybody have any idea how I would analyse this data using an ANOVA in R? Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Hey, maybe think about it this way, you are trying to look at the rate of have 0 in accuracy due to hand or parity, while controlling for participant effect.

Comment: Hence you need the 1s. You should do a logistic regression on accuracy. I need to check if type3 anova is possible with that, but otherwise you can also use a linear mixed model (say lme4). Maybe you can provide a subset of the data, say with 5 participants? Including the 1s

Comment: Yeah, per @StupidWolf, I think you want to summarize your data at the participant level first, then conduct your analysis. And the error rate seems to be the summary stat you want.

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you for your comment! I'm not sure I'm interested in the rate of 0's in comparison to 1's. I just want to compare the number of errors when the the subject uses their left or right hand, or when they respond to odd or even numbers. However, I've edited the post to include an example that contains 1's form 5 participants.

Comment: hi @codegoblin1996, yes I understand you want to know the number of 0s. This is only valid when you have the same number of trials, therefore you need the information from observations that give you 1s.

Comment: @StupidWolf okay I see (just done some reading). Would multiple logistic regression be more suitable for my data?

Comment: Yes. multiple logistic regression. glm(accuracy ~ parity * hand+participant, family="binomial") first. This is take participant as a fixed effect. To do repeated measurement, you might need a linear mixed

Comment: hi @StupidWolf I have performed this analysis. The estimate for handright:parityodd is 0.7967725 and statistically significant p < 0.05. Does this indicate an increase in probability of an accurate response under those conditions?

Comment: hey.. chances are yes.. But I think you should check the data again to see whether it reflects that. And without seeing the data myself, I cannot comment much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205943/discussion-between-codegoblin1996-and-stupidwolf).